# Dynamic class declaration, using variable to name class and variable reference to dynamic class

Tags: python, class, variables, dynamic, python-3.x

I need to generate 1000+ classes from a list.

1) In my case, my list is *NOT* user specified. The content can be trusted, I build the list content myself. Therefore I can use eval() without introducing security risk. However, I would like to know if there are alternatives way of doing entry = eval(c_class)()

2) Instead of re-using the entry variable, I would like to build variables names from the class_list_names. I.e.: rak_entry = rak()  ...  bak_entry = bak() .

```
exec("entry_"+c_class +" = eval(c_class)()")
```

Are there other ways than to use exec with eval? 
Here's my code

```
class_list_names = ['rak', 'bak', 'sak', 'mak']

class pattern_class(object):
    generic_attr = "bla"

def declare(classname):
    globals()[classname] = type(classname, (pattern_class,), {'__tablename__' : classname+"_daily_history"})

for c_class in class_list_names:
    declare(c_class)
    entry = eval(c_class)()
    print(entry)
    print(entry.__tablename__)
    print(entry.generic_attr)
```

output

```
<__main__.rak object at 0x0242D950>
rak_daily_history
bla
<__main__.bak object at 0x0242DA10>
bak_daily_history
bla
<__main__.sak object at 0x0242D9B0>
sak_daily_history
bla
<__main__.mak object at 0x0242D950>
mak_daily_history
bla
```

Regards

Comment: Why don't you use `globals()[c_class]()` as you did in `declare`?

Comment: Or you can make `declare` to return the generated class object, then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `declare` to return generated class.

```
class pattern_class(object):
    generic_attr = "bla"

def declare(classname):
    return type(classname, (pattern_class,), {'__tablename__' : classname+"_daily_history"})

class_list_names = ['rak', 'bak', 'sak', 'mak']
for name in class_list_names:
    cls = declare(name)
    globals()[name + '_entry'] = cls()

print rak_entry.__tablename__, bak_entry.__tablename__, sak_entry.__tablename__, mak_entry.__tablename__
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using globals()[c_class]() that works great. It answers my first question.

However for my second question, I can't write the variables name by hand (rak_entry, ...) because I will have more than 1000+ classes.